# installing svn on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android-studio, svn

Problem occurred when installing subversion on Ubuntu 16.04.

After installing the apache2 server and creating the repository, after that I got this error while connecting to repository by the following commands:

Begin by installing the Subversion package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install subversion
$ sudo mkdir /usr/local/svn
```

Inside this directory, create another one to hold your repositories:

```
$ sudo mkdir /usr/local/svn/repos
$ sudo groupadd svn
$ sudo chgrp svn /usr/local/svn/repos
$ sudo chmod g+w /usr/local/svn/repos
$ sudo usermod -a -G svn michal
$ groups
$ umask 002 
$ svn checkout file:///usr/local/svn/repos/test
Checked out revision 0.
The working copy has been checked out to a new directory named test. Go ahead and create a simple "hello world" text file in that directory:

$ cd test
$ echo 'Hello, World!' > hello.txt
```

Then, add it to version control with the svn add command:

```
$ svn add hello
A         hello
```

Finally, commit it using svn commit:

```
$ svn commit -m "Added a 'hello world' text file."
Adding         hello
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 1.
```

I am using the below command to checkout file:

```
sudo svn checkout file:///var/svn/repos/test                                                                
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///var/svn/repos/test'
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///var/svn/repos/test'
```

Please help me on this issue.

Thanks in advance, Meena.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Iam trying to use the svn on ubuntu16.04  ,In the process of creating a test repository,i got the following errors                                                                            vconnect4@vconnect4-H81M-S:/test$ svn cleanup
svn: E200031: sqlite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database
svn: E200042: Additional errors:
svn: E200031: sqlite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database
plz help me,

Comment: That's nowhere near enough info. How did you install and set up Apache with SVN? How exactly did you are trying to initialise the repository? **Again, please *[edit]* your post to add information instead of posting a comment.** Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.